Has anyone used Arkworks with Spartan?
I'm trying to use Spartan to produce and verify zkSNARKS. I want to use Arkworks (https://github.com/arkworks-rs) to create custom R1CS instances, but Arkworks does not readily interface with Spartan. I know there are some other tools like CirC that already interface with Spartan, but I have decided that Arkworks is best for the particular needs of my project.
Has anyone successfully used Arkworks to create R1CS instances to use as inputs for Spartan? I can write R1CS constraints using the crypto-primitives crate in Arkworks, but I don't know how to turn these constraints into an R1CS instance that interface with Spartan's API like verify or prove.
For example, from Spartan's README, this is how to use libspartan to create and verify a SNARK proof. How can I turn an Arkworks R1CS constraints into the (inst, vars, inputs) that Spartan seems to require?
```rust
# extern crate libspartan;
# extern crate merlin;
# use libspartan::{Instance, SNARKGens, SNARK};
# use merlin::Transcript;
# use ark_bls12_381::{G1Projective, Fr};
#
# fn main() {
    // specify the size of an R1CS instance
    let num_vars = 1024;
    let num_cons = 1024;
    let num_inputs = 10;
    let num_non_zero_entries = 1024;

    // produce public parameters
    let gens = SNARKGens::<G1Projective>::new(num_cons, num_vars, num_inputs, num_non_zero_entries);

    // ask the library to produce a synthentic R1CS instance
    let (inst, vars, inputs) = Instance::produce_synthetic_r1cs(num_cons, num_vars, num_inputs);

    // create a commitment to the R1CS instance
    let (comm, decomm) = SNARK::encode(&inst, &gens);

    // produce a proof of satisfiability
    let mut prover_transcript = Transcript::new(b"snark_example");
    let proof = SNARK::prove(&inst, &comm, &decomm, vars, &inputs, &gens, &mut prover_transcript);

    // verify the proof of satisfiability
    let mut verifier_transcript = Transcript::new(b"snark_example");
    assert!(proof
      .verify(&comm, &inputs, &mut verifier_transcript, &gens)
      .is_ok());
    println!("proof verification successful!");
# }

What are some detailed steps or caveats if anyone has tried wiring these up before?
Thank you!
